# My compiler doesn't support transparent unions. How do I get around that?

Tags: c

I am trying to port a program that uses the GCC transparent union extension but the compiler I need to use doesn't support them. When I compile the program I get a mismatch between the caller and the function prototype. I think all I have to do is add a cast to each caller, but I am not sure. What is the easiest way to code around this lack in the compiler?

The code I am trying to port is Quagga 1.1.0. The OS is Solaris with the Oracle Studio compiler.

Here is the error I get:

> quagga-1.1.0/lib/zclient.c", line 1030: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
>           prototype: union prefix46constptr {pointer to const struct prefix {..} p, pointer to const struct prefix_ipv4 {..} p4, pointer to
>   const struct prefix_ipv6 {..} p6} : "quagga-1.1.0/lib/prefix.h", line
>   228
>           argument : pointer to struct prefix {unsigned char family, unsigned char prefixlen, union  {..} u}

Here is the function being called:

```
const char *
prefix2str (union prefix46constptr pu, char *str, int size)
{
```

Here is the line where the function is called:

```
prefix2str (ifc->address, buf, sizeof buf))
```

And here are the transparent unions:

```
union prefix46ptr
{
  struct prefix *p;
  struct prefix_ipv4 *p4;
  struct prefix_ipv6 *p6;
} __attribute__ ((transparent_union));

union prefix46constptr
{
  const struct prefix *p;
  const struct prefix_ipv4 *p4;
  const struct prefix_ipv6 *p6;
} __attribute__ ((transparent_union));
```

Here is the whole function:

```
const char *
prefix2str (union prefix46constptr pu, char *str, int size)
{
  const struct prefix *p = pu.p;
  char buf[BUFSIZ];

  if (p->family == AF_ETHERNET) {
    int         i;
    char        *s = str;

    assert(size > (3*ETHER_ADDR_LEN) + 1 /* slash */ + 3 /* plen */ );
    for (i = 0; i < ETHER_ADDR_LEN; ++i) {
        sprintf(s, "%02x", p->u.prefix_eth.octet[i]);
        if (i < (ETHER_ADDR_LEN - 1)) {
            *(s+2) = ':';
            s += 3;
        } else {
            s += 2;
        }
    }
    sprintf(s, "/%d", p->prefixlen);
    return 0;
  }

  inet_ntop (p->family, &p->u.prefix, buf, BUFSIZ);
  snprintf (str, size, "%s/%d", buf, p->prefixlen);
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Seems like there's no way around rewriting that code base. Compiler extension should not be used unless they are behind a firm compilation firewall. Unless you *never* want to port to another compiler

Comment: "What is the easiest way to code around this lack in the compiler?" Refactor transparent unions out of your codebase.

Comment: You may also need to mention which compiler (in which version) you are using.

Comment: We need to see the type of the argument being called (i.e. "ifc->address) and how the function uses this arguments (i.e. how is "pu" is used in "prefix2str".

Comment: ifc is declared like this:

`struct connected *ifc;`

Comment: Please post the definitions of `struct prefix`, `struct prefix_ipv6`, `struct prefix_ipb4`

Comment: you can define the signature of the called function to be a `void *` and include a `void *` entry in the union.  Then just call the function with the void pointer and let the called function decide what the actual type needs to be.   Similar to how the last parameter to `pthread_create()` is called and how the actual thread gets back the actual type via an assignment.

Comment: When asked for a **minimal, compilable** and verifiable testcase, it isn't good enough to paste code which 1/ violates the "minimal" property by introducing bloat (you don't need that entire function body to reproduce the issue) and 2/ violates the "compilable" quality by *still failing to compile*!

Comment: Noting [the type of `ifc->address`](https://github.com/opensourcerouting/quagga/blob/68bfb6190e19898adc0e420b6346cf4778705e60/lib/if.h#L294) is **required** to produce a **complete and verifiable testcase**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, StackOverflow is (at least, in my opinion) not a place where you go to submit bugs for a project. Bug reports should be submitted in a mailing list or bug tracker for the project in question.

In this case, it seems a non-standard feature has been used where a standard feature would suffice. Remove `__attribute__ ((transparent_union))` and `const struct prefix *p = pu.p;`, and replace `union prefix46constptr pu` with `const struct prefix *p`.

You'll also most likely need to modify some code in headers, and make other changes which should be done by whoever is fixing the bug. I assume they're competent C programmers and will understand how to do that... but then again, they should understand how to make the above changes, too!

There are times when a design is just too cromulent to deal with, and this is one of those times. I advise seeking other alternatives, if you can! One should not simply *hack IPV6 support in as though IPV4 functions can be modified to produce the required functionality*.